# Legend.labels.template implementation

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-chart

My implementation has been working fine until I have added

`legend.labels.template = "# dataItem.fName # ";`

I want to format legend to make it same with tooltip.

```
legend:{
  visible:true,
  labels:
  {
    template: "#= dataItem.fname #"
  }
},
```

Here is [**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/s8mywm33/10/).

In this fiddle, when you commented out `legend.label.templates`, then it does not work.

Comment: Use this `template: "#= console.log(data) #"` to see what's going on on the data structure, then i found out there is no dataitem.fname there, it's deeper inside.

Comment: As a warning, please stop using comments to direct people to your questions. A number of these were just flagged, and I removed all the ones I could find. This is not a proper use of comments.

Comment: oh, ok. sorry I did not know that. Thanks Brad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One quick solution might be to name your series for the fname:

```
   series: [{
        type: "column",
        field: "value",
        stack: true,
        name: "#= group.items[0].fname || group.items[1].fname #",
        highlight: {
            visible: false,
        }
    }],
```

### Updated **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/s8mywm33/15/)**

Answer (score 1):

Error on console said that `dataItem` is **undefined**. I don't know why, otherwise you can make a function to grab fname from joined `data` collection.

This is your variable `data` code

```
data = data.reduce(function (a, b) {
        return a.concat(b)
      });
console.log(data);
```

change your template can be like this

```
legend:{
  visible:true,
  labels:
  {
    template: "#= getLegendLabelBy(text) #"
  }
},
```

and make a function for it

```
function getLegendLabelBy(data) {
   var label = "";
   // do loop through data and grab match data by its series name
   for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
       var series = data[i].series;

       // condition operation here and assign label value
       //.......
   }

   return label;
}
```

Comment: When I run your approach, it says `getLegendLabelBy()` is not recognized. How could I handle it?

Comment: you should define that function on your javascript file bro